# Selecting only one row at a time for iteration in PANDAS-PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have this following code and a text file with 5 (X and Y) values [The Image of the text file is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSLEp.jpg). I need to iterate 1000 times for every X and Y value. How can I achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd
data   = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True,)

for every line in the text document:
    for i in range(1, 1001, 1):
        z = data["X"] + data["Y"]
        z = z + 10
    print z
```

The text file is like

```
X Y
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
```

The output must be:

```
10011 
10022
10033
10044
10055
```

Comment: i didn't get what you exactly want , can you provide text file contents instead of image. and expected output

Comment: The output must be:                                                                           
10011
10022
10033
10044
10055

Comment: what operation you done on X and Y you get this output.

Comment: But your code `data["X"] + data["Y"] + '10'` does not return `[10011, ...]`, but rather `[11010, ...]`

Comment: I just need pandas to select one row of data at a time.

Comment: @ammy: just keep adding 10 to X+Y  for thousand times. But, as vince pointed out the output should rather be [11010, ...]

Comment: @VinceP: Yes you are right, please assist me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add new column to dataFrame:

```
data["total"] = sorted(set([(data.loc[ix]['X'].astype(int) + data.loc[ix]['Y'].astype(int)).astype(str) +"10" for ix in data.index for i in range(1,1001)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select one row at the time using `.loc`. Please read this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to fully understand how this work. Here is your data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Y': ['10','20','30','40','50']})
```

This code

```
print df.loc[0]
```

will give you the first row (with index=0) as a pandas series (`pd.Series`), which is essentially like a dataframe with one column only: a vector.

```
X     1
Y    10
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If you want the second row then: `df.loc[1]` and so on...

If you want to iterate one row at the time, you can select each row in the first for loop and perform your operations 1000 times in the second for loop:

```
for ix in df.index:   # df.index gives [0,1,2,3,4]
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
        ser = df.loc[ix]
        print ser['X'] + ser['Y'] + '10'
```

Comment: @Siva D: you want X and Y addition or concat

Comment: should be "+ 10", not "+ '10'". you get an error ```numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Y': [10,20,30,40,50]})

for each_line in data.index:
    z = data['X'].loc[each_line] + data['Y'].loc[each_line]
    for i in range(1,1001,1):
        z +=10
    print(z)

Output
10011
10022
10033
10044
10055
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want concatenate the 'X' and 'Y' +'10' then:

```
[data.loc[ix]['X'].astype(str) + data.loc[ix]['Y'].astype(str) +"10" for ix in data.index for i in range(1,1001)]
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to sum of 'X' + 'Y' and concat + '10' then:

```
final_data = [(data.loc[ix]['X'].astype(int) + data.loc[ix]['Y'].astype(int)).astype(str) +"10" for ix in data.index for i in range(1,1001)]
```